# Graph from adjacency list, can't get weight to work

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, adjacency-list

I made this graph to take a commands "create 4" and "insert 3 2 1", i.e. create adjacency list of 4 and node 3 connects to node 2 with weight 1.

I can't seem to get it to take the weight correctly, I'm trying to make an adjacency list like:

```
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]->[2][1]
```

I would appreciate it if someone could give some ideas how to fix this.

here my code: 
main.cpp

```
using namespace std;
#include "graph.h"

//Main Function 
int main(){

string command;
int src,dest,wght,size;
graph A(size);  //initial class instance

//handles all I/O
do{
    cout << "graph>";
    cin >> command;

    //Creates an array of size "size" for nodes to be added too
    if(command == "create"){

        cin>>size;
        graph A(size);
    }
    //Tests for user insertion of node
    else if(command == "insert"){

        cin >> src >> dest >> wght;
        if(src <= size && dest <= size){
            A.insert(src, dest, wght);
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Error! Node does not exist!"<<endl;
        }
    }

    //Tests for user removal of node
    else if(command == "remove"){

        cin >> src >> dest;
        if(src <= size && dest <= size){
            A.remove(src, dest);
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Error! Node does not exist!"<<endl;
        }
    }

    //Tests for user printing of graph
    else if(command == "print"){
        A.print();     
    }

    else{
        if(command != "quit")
            cout<<"Error! Command not supported."<<endl;
    }

}while(command != "quit" );


 return 0;
}
```

graph.h

```
//graph class file
using namespace std;
#include "node.h"

class graph{
    private:
        int h;
        class alist* array;
    public:

        //Initializes the Graph and fills it with NULLs
        graph(int h){
            this->h = h;
            array = new alist [h];
            for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
                array[i].head = NULL;
        }

        //Creates a new node by calling instance newlist of listnode
        listnode* newlist(int dest){
            listnode* newnode = new listnode;
                newnode->dest = dest;
                    newnode->next = NULL;
            return newnode;
        }

        //Connects the node of the Graph
        void insert(int src, int dest, int weight){

            listnode* newnode = newlist(dest);
                newnode->next = array[src].head;
                    array[src].head = newnode;
                        newnode = newlist(src);
                            newnode = newlist(weight);
                                newnode->next = array[dest].head;

        }

        //Removes a node from the graph
        void remove(int srcr, int destr){

            for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i){

                listnode* move = array[i].head;
                while (move){
                    if(destr == move->dest){
                        if(srcr==i)
                            array[i].head = NULL;
                    }
                move = move->next;
                }                 
            }
        }

        //Prints the Graph      
        void print(){

            for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i){

                listnode* move = array[i].head;
                while (move){
                    cout<<"("<<i <<","<< move->dest<< ","<< move->weight <<")";
                    move = move->next;
                }  
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
};
```

node.h

```
//node class file
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"

//Nodes
class listnode
{
    public:
    int dest;
    int weight;
    class listnode* next;
};
```

list.h

```
//list class file
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

//Adjacency List
class alist
{
    public:
    class listnode *head;
};
```

Comment: Could you tell us what you enter exactly, and what the outpu is that makes you thnk that it didn't work ?

Comment: In main() you should include <string> and most of all, initialise size before using it in the Graph() constructor !!  Uniti variables never yields good results !

Comment: Your if() for the creation command recreates a new Graph A(), but this is a local valriable whose scope is only within the if() { } bloc. As soon as you exit the bloc, this temporary Graph is destoyed and all aother references to A refer to the A from the bery begining of main()

Comment: The output should be (3,2,1) but it is (3,2,0), the exact input is in the question, shown by " ". Also when I try to create the graph outside of that I/O function it gives syntax errors about it not being declared in this scope.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your code.

First, never use unitialised variables in constructors:

```
int src,dest,wght,size=10;   // put an intial value for size
                  ^^^^^^^^
graph A(size);               // because your constructor used an unitialised size so far
```

Then you have to review the implementation of your create command, because currently, you do this:

```
    if (command == "create"){
        cin >> size;
        graph A(size);    // this is a local object of the if bloc 
    }                     // which gets destroyed when you reach this brace !!!!!
```

You could for example implement a resize() function and call it instead of recreating a new graph that immediately vanishes.

Then your insert() function is called with right parameters, but doesn't update the node's weight.  Please see hints here:

```
void insert(int src, int dest, int weight){  
    listnode* newnode = newlist(dest); 
    newnode->next = array[src].head; 
    newnode->weight = weight;      // <========= Update your node weight with this...  
    array[src].head = newnode;  
    newnode = newlist(src); 
    //newnode = newlist(weight);   // <========  But what's this ?  Remove it ! 
    newnode->next = array[dest].head;
}
```

After these corrections it works:  command "insert 3 2 1"  followed by "print" will lead to the correct result.

Nevertheless, I'd strongly advise to use the standard library [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) which would make your life much easier !

Comment: Thank you Christophe! That worked perfectly, I went on to try and do a DFS function of the graph, something like "DFS 1", ie start the DFS at node 1, then print nodes visited in order but I'm stumped, any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds an interesting topic for opening a new question, and mark this one as completed !